# Running AsyncTask after delay does not trigger onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                asyncTask(param);
            }
        }, 5000);
```

AND TRIED:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "ENTERED");
                asyncTask(param);
            }
        }, 5000);
```

This portion of code is ran on the onCreate method and for some reason, when i debug and put Log.d in the onPostExecute, it never entered.

I need to run the task after 5s delay, AND get the results from onPostExecute, is there a workaround?

Thanks. The onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "NOPE");
    listener.onFetchFinished(result);
}
```

Also: the doInBackground returns successfully, so it is not the cause.

EDIT: Pasted more codes:

```
    private void asyncTask(int param) {
    AsyncTask pc = new AsyncTask (getApplicationContext(), listener);
    pc.execute(moreParams);}
```

Comment: post your asyncTask(param);

Comment: why are you adding that unnecessary delay using handler, is there any other code executing in it?

Comment: Did you check whether doInBackground() executing first?

Comment: Could it be due to encapsulated thread ? Since onPostExecute is supposed to execute on UIThread, but you launch the AsyncTask from outside UIThread (from your timer thread) ?

Comment: @GaneshGudghe uploaded, it calls the actual async task from that method, and the listener processes the data to be fetched after onPostExecute is called.

Comment: @KaranMer Yes, i do some processing in between. Basically the asynctask should only be executed after around 5s - allows for whatever happens before to settle in

Comment: @BaluSangem Yes, my log.d's get called right before return

Comment: @vincrichaud It might be, but I am unable to find another solution to 'launch an asynctask after delay' as handler.postDelayed is also outside UIThread

Comment: @Parablaine might be ugly but, you could launch an AsyncTask that just sleep for 5seconds, and onPostExecute start your Asynctask. Or you might directly start your asynctask, but the doInBackground start with a 5sec sleep

Comment: @vincrichaud I have tried the latter - sleep in doInBackground, and somehow the onPostExecute doesnt get executed after i added the sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem is "calling from different thread".

this may work for you

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
handler.posteDelayed({asyncTask(param)},5000)
```

Comment: Hello, just tried this, the postDelayed doesnt get executed at all... this is placed in my onCreate() of the activity.

Comment: Can you post the code?,if you are calling it from activity oncreate() ,you don't need to specify looper also

Comment: //@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//some other codes here

final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ENTERED");
                    asyncTask(param);
                }
            }, 5000);

Comment: I tried the non-looper way before, and the onPostExecute doesnt get called. 
- I tried new Handler(); before

Comment: I have tried post delayed called after 5 seconds. For you its not coming to this : Log.d(TAG, "ENTERED")??

Comment: Yes sir, even the log is not being called, tried on both handlers - with and without looper

Comment: https://gist.github.com/BALUSANGEM/a460e11dcff89bcad6ef2193b6f5706d try this, which is working for me, Lmk